# How to prevent score from being overwritten when the same activity is called

Tags: android, android-activity, save

I am creating a memory game. After the user have finished the game, he can start a new game. In order to play a new game, I decided to call the activity itself again. However, when the activity is called again, the score goes back to 0, as it was initialized. I was wondering if I could save the previous score and prevent being overwritten even If I call the same activity again.

```
 Check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Answer.setText("You got "+Integer.toString(correct)+" correct answers.");

        } 
  });

   newGame.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent i = new Intent(Game.this, Game.class);
            i.putExtra("name", name);
            startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use `SharedPreferences` to store the score. This is a really good way to store simple but persistent data.[The Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) have a good example of how to do this. You will save them in your `onClick()` or whereever you want. Then you can check if that preference has a value when you start the `Activity`. If so then you have your old score to do whatever you want with.

The basic steps will be to store them by creating an instance of `SharedPreferences.Editor` (be sure to call `commit()` after you write to the preference. then you use the `getSharedPreferences` method to retrieve them in your first `Activity`. That link has a very good example of using them.

[Full SharedPreference Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

If you don't need to have the data persistent when the app is closed and depending what else you are doing with it, you could also just pass it as an `extra` in the `Intent` like you are with `name` but `SharedPreferences` may be better depending on your needs.

Comment: Can I use the score obtained to store it in sqlite?

Comment: Yes, but if this is all you will use the DB for then `SharedPreferences` would be simpler and easier.

Comment: No. I was planning to design the app to have the ability to create username and store their scores, and also display the previous player's names and scores. it's like showing player and player score history.

Comment: Oh, then you don't need `SharedPreferences`. Just store them in your DB and get them from here. [SQLite DB](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Comment: passing is as an intent. I should have figured that out. Anyway, I'm still new to Android and thank you very much for your help!